# Adding outlet to kitchen cabinet with a gap

Tags: electrical, kitchens

I've finally gotten around to installing an outlet into my kitchen cabinets that were put in by the previous owners. Below is a picture of what I am working with.

[image]

[image]

As you can see the wire is already there but there seems to be no cutout or anything, along with a gap between the cabinet and wall. I have an Old Work box from a previous project but will that work? Or is there a box or method specifically for this kind of job? Thank you!

********************************* Completed ***********************************

Here is the finished product for anyone who is interested:

[image]

[image]

Comment: would you want to use a surface mount box for this sort of work?  It would take away some interior volume from the cabinet, but it'd work.

Comment: @Aaron I've never heard of a surface mount box, do you have a recommendation of one? I don't mind losing some space if it means less cutting!

Comment: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/_hVwczZ2PFM/maxresdefault.jpg something like that  except obviously with the wire not coming out of the wall and into the box, but all behind/in the box

Comment: @aaron that looks kinda-not-codey.

Comment: @Harper I know, I couldn't find one that was done correctly but having the box protrude into the cabinet is the right "idea", or at least the idea I was trying to convey for this example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use and 4-square commercial metal box, available from the big box stores or any home center/large hardware store.  Knock out a hole in the back of the box, insert a pop-in NM connector install the wire through the connector and screw the box to the back of the cabinet.  Purchase a single gang mud ring.  install the ring on the box.  Install the receptacle and the plate.

Comment: What is a pop-in NM connector?

Comment: Walk in to a **proper electrical supply house**.  "What is a pop-in NM connector?" "What are you trying to do?" "Bring Romex into a knockout on a metal box."  "Be right back."....."It's one of these."   The exact same conversation will happen at Home Depot, except he'll bring you the wrong thing.  Probably a can of paint.

Comment: Non-metallic quick fit NM cable connector.

Comment: AKA push button connector

Comment: In case anyone is wondering how I solved this. As @Harper said, I went to a local electrical supply store, the man working there was incredibly knowledgeable, told me everything I wanted to know, and sold me what I needed. He gave me everything described above and actually threw in some extra stuff for free. For sure a better place to get the knowledge I needed than the local Big Box.

Comment: Looks awesome, like a pro!